# Get date Parameter URL SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using an SSRS report in a bookmark. I am able to set parameters like &Person=Bob in the URL however I want to set the date to today's date. Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I am able to do StartDate=22/02/2017 but this has to be changed manually everyday on the bookmark.

Comment: Do you need to pass the date as part of the URL? Would it not be easier to leave it out, and have the date be set by default to today's date in the report itself?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this as the report needs to be left as that default date it's currently set as. So would need to pass it in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically generate a link to the report with the current date in a tool like Excel or on a basic web page with some JavaScript. But not in a browser bookmark.